# Mask xarray Dataset on one dimension

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray dataset with variables with dimensions `(time, x, y)` or `(x, y)`. I addition, I have an array with bools the same size as the `time` dimension, which I would like to use to filter my dataset. I can't get that working.

Simple example that does work (all variables have the same dimensions):

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

# Create dummy dataset:
data_vars = {
        'var1': (['time', 'y', 'x'], np.arange(81).reshape(9,3,3))} 
coords = {'time': (['time'], np.arange(9))}
ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars=data_vars, coords=coords)

# Define mask. Simple in this case, more complex patterns in real-life problem:
mask = (ds.time.values > 2) & (ds.time.values < 6)

# Mask dataset. 
ds_masked = ds.where(mask[: ,np.newaxis, np.newaxis])
ds_final = ds_masked.dropna(dim='time')
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way of applying a mask, but at least it works. But if I add a variable with different dims:

```
data_vars = {
        'var1': (['time', 'y', 'x'], np.arange(81).reshape(9,3,3)), 
        'var2': (['y', 'x'], np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))}
```

and leave the rest of the code unchanged, I can no longer filter my dataset, because my mask has more dimensions than `var2`. Any idea how to easily do this? I would like to keep `var2` in the filtered dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xarray supports indexing with 1-D boolean arrays. So either of your examples will work with:

```
ds_final = ds.sel(time=mask)
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple solution, thanks!